# How to make method getUserById

Tags: java, methods, hashmap

I need to make a method getUserById witch will return 1 user by its id. I think that I need to use HashMap so here is my method :

```
 public class UserDao {
    private static final String SELECT_USERS = "select * from users_Alana";
    public static List<User> getUsers(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        return jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_USERS,new UserMapper());
    }

    private static class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User> {
        @Nullable
        public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            user.setGender(resultSet.getString("gender"));
            user.setAge(resultSet.getInt("age"));
            return user;
        }
    }
    public static void getUserById(int number) throws SQLException {
        HashMap<Integer,User> getUser = new HashMap<Integer, User>();
        if (getUser.containsKey(number)) {
            System.out.println(getUser);
        }
    }
}
```

I call this method in a main class by `UserDao.getUserById(2);` Also I have a class User (with int id, age; String name, gender;) Constructor, getters and setters in it.
The result is nothing. How to solve it?

Comment: Where do you call getUserById?

Comment: Also, your HashMap is empty, do it can't do anything till till you feed it values

Comment: @Ayush Gupta I call it in my main method by UserDao.getUserById(2);        Also i have a class User (with int id, age; String name, gender;) Constructor, getters and setters in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the user by id, I don't think you need a `HashMap` you can just use :

```
public static void getUserById(int id) throws SQLException {
    UserDao dao = new UserDao();
    List<User> users = dao.getUsers(jdbcTemplate);//This return a List or users
    User user = user.stream()
            .filter(u -> u.getId() == id)// filter the user by id
            .findFirst()// if find then return the first
            .orElseGet(User::new);// else return new User()
}
```

---

But it can be better to create a second query to get user by id :

```
private static final String SELECT_USERS_BY_ID = "select * from users_Alana WHERE id = ?1";
```

Comment: Honestly though, A direct DB with the condition would be much more efficient

Comment: i was typing when you post this comment @AyushGupta yes, the better solution is to use a new query instead, i just correct the OP's mistake

Comment: @YCF_L I think it could be, but the main idea to do it with help of method

Comment: what did you mean @MaksymSereda ?

Comment: @ YCF_L I mean that I need to use method, not a query

Comment: @YCF_L could you please help me to fix it?  I did the following                                        public static void getUserById(int id) throws SQLException {
        UserDao dao = new UserDao();
        List<User> users = dao.getUsers(jdbcTemplate);//This return a List or users
        User user = users.stream()
                .filter(u -> u.getId() == id)// filter the user by id
                .findFirst()// if find then return the first
                .orElse(new User());// else return new User()
    }

Comment: and there mistakes              Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
[User id 1, age 28, name Anton, gender m, User id 2, age 30, name Mary, gender f, User id 3, age 29, name Davi, gender m, User id 4, age 24, name Luiza, gender f, User id 5, age 32, name Lisa, gender f, User id 6, age 38, name Lucas, gender m, User id 7, age 38, name Phelipe, gender m, User id 8, age 37, name Anna, gender f]
 at dao.UserDao.getUsers(UserDao.java:18)
 at dao.UserDao.getUserById(UserDao.java:35)
 at Example.Lesson25.JdbcTemplateEx.main(JdbcTemplateEx.java:20)

Comment: can you post this in your question please?

Comment: @MaksymSereda I'm sorry, i think you have to use `orElseGet(User::new)` instead or `orElse`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the `User` object from the `getUser`

```
public static User getUserById(int number) throws SQLException {
    HashMap<Integer,User> getUser = new HashMap<Integer, User>();
    return getUser.get(number);        
}
```

You do need to populate the `HashMap` with the values though

Comment: did u populate the HashMap?

Comment: I need my method return values from SQL table, this table is exist. I just need to unite SQL with java (I hope I correctly expressed my idea)

Comment: See @YCF_L's answer